# Oracle SQL - need to build a WHERE clause based on a list of paired values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of addresses, split into STREET_NUMBER and STREET_NAME, and associated fields. I'd like to search the table for a specific list of addresses. I can run single-address queries using the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE STREET_NUMBER = '123'
  AND STREET_NAME LIKE '%MAIN%'
```

How can I set up the WHERE clause to accept a list of STREET_NAME/STREET_NUMBER pairs? Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE STREET_NUMBER IN ('123', '231', '5245', '73334')
  AND STREET_NAME LIKE ('%MAIN%', '%ELM%', '%BROAD%', '%FIRST%')
```

The intent is to pull any records where the address is close to:

| Number | Street |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Main |
| 231 | Elm |
| 5245 | Broad |
| 73334 | Third |

I need something similar to LIKE functionality for STREET_NAME as the values in that column are not very clean - all include street extensions, but they are inconsistent ("Road" vs. "Rd'; "Avenue" vs. "Ave", etc.).

This will be an ad hoc use case. Poor performance is not a concern.

Comment: Since you need to wildcard street names then I would consider simply using a bunch of OR statements and parenthesis. `WHERE (cond1) or (cond2) or (cond3)... `

Comment: I should note that this will be an ad hoc query. Poor performance isn't much of a concern. (added this comment the question body)

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to do that in "regular" SQL elegantly and effectively.
You either have to start using Oracle Text or replicate your data into Elasticsearch.

```
Select * from TABLE
WHERE 1=0
or (STREET_NUMBER = '123' and STREET_NAME LIKE '%MAIN%')
or (STREET_NUMBER = '231' and STREET_NAME LIKE '%ELM%')
or (STREET_NUMBER = '5245' AND STREET_NAME LIKE '%BROAD%')
or (STREET_NUMBER = '73334' AND STREET_NAME LIKE '%FIRST%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to correct inconsistencies making your own substutitions. To be able to do this you should know what abreviations or variations are used

```sql
WITH        --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    addresses AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", 'Main Road' "STREET",     123 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 "ID", 'Elm Street' "STREET",     34 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "ID", 'Broad Avenue' "STREET",    1 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 4 "ID", 'Third Str.' "STREET",     23 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 5 "ID", 'Broad Av' "STREET",       12 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 6 "ID", 'Av. Broad' "STREET",     111 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 7 "ID", 'Main Rd.' "STREET",     5104 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 8 "ID", 'Elm Str' "STREET",      3498 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 9 "ID", 'Third Street' "STREET", 1001 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 10 "ID", 'John Doe''s str.' "STREET", 1001 "NMBR" From Dual Union All
          Select 11 "ID", 'Str John Doe''s' "STREET", 1001 "NMBR" From Dual 
        ),
```

Create CTE (abreviations) to define which of the variations you want to substitute with which TXT. Format variations string with the delimiter at start, between the variations and at end of string. Delimiter could be anything that is not present in your data. Make it all in capital letters cause that could be a problem too. Later it will be compared with Upper() function making capitalization of original data irrelevant.

```sql
  abreviations AS 
    ( Select 'STREET' "TXT", '*STREET*STR*STR.*'    "VARIANTS" From Dual Union All 
      Select 'ROAD'   "TXT", '*ROAD*RD*RD.*'        "VARIANTS" From Dual Union All 
      Select 'AVENUE' "TXT", '*AVENUE*AVE*AV*AV.*'  "VARIANTS" From Dual 
    ),
```

next, create another CTE (grid) to transform and break apart the original street from your data:

```sql
  grid AS
    ( Select  a.ID, a.NMBR, a.STREET,
              Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|') "STREET_2",
              SubStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'),
                      2,
                      InStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'), '|', 1, 2) - 2 
                    ) "PART_1",
              SubStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'),
                      InStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'), '|', 1, 2) + 1,
                      (InStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'), '|', 1, 3) + 1) -
                      InStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'), '|', 1, 2) - 2
                    ) "PART_2",
              SubStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'),
                      InStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'), '|', 1, 3) + 1,
                      (InStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'), '|', 1, 4) + 1) -
                      InStr( Replace('|' || Replace(Replace(a.STREET, '.', '.|'), ' ', '|') || '|', '||', '|'), '|', 1, 3) - 2
                    ) "PART_3"
      From    addresses a
    )
```

```sql
/*    grid      R e s u l t :
ID    NMBR  STREET          STREET_2          PART_1    PART_2    PART_3
--  ------  --------------- ----------------  --------  --------  --------
1      123  Main Road       |Main|Road|       Main      Road    
2       34  Elm Street      |Elm|Street|      Elm       Street  
3        1  Broad Avenue    |Broad|Avenue|    Broad     Avenue  
4       23  Third Str.      |Third|Str.|      Third     Str.    
5       12  Broad Av        |Broad|Av|        Broad     Av  
6      111  Av. Broad       |Av.|Broad|       Av.       Broad   
7     5104  Main Rd.        |Main|Rd.|        Main      Rd. 
8     3498  Elm Str         |Elm|Str|         Elm       Str 
9     1001  Third Street    |Third|Street|    Third     Street  
10    1001  John Doe's str. |John|Doe's|str.| John      Doe's     str.      
11    1001  Str John Doe's  |Str|John|Doe's|  Str       John      Doe's */
```

Now you can get uniformed addresses making sustitutions where needed:

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select  g.ID, g.NMBR, g.STREET,
  InitCap( 
    Replace(TRIM(
        Replace(Upper(g.STREET), Case  When InStr(a.VARIANTS, '*' || Upper(g.PART_1) || '*') > 0 Then Upper(g.PART_1)
                                       When InStr(a.VARIANTS, '*' || Upper(g.PART_2) || '*') > 0 Then Upper(g.PART_2)
                                       When InStr(a.VARIANTS, '*' || Upper(g.PART_3) || '*') > 0 Then Upper(g.PART_3)
                                 End, '') 
        || ' ' ||
        Case  When InStr(a.VARIANTS, '*' || Upper(g.PART_1) || '*') > 0 Then a.TXT 
              When InStr(a.VARIANTS, '*' || Upper(g.PART_2) || '*') > 0 Then a.TXT 
              When InStr(a.VARIANTS, '*' || Upper(g.PART_3) || '*') > 0 Then a.TXT 
        End 
      ),
   '  ', ' ') ) "NEW_STREET"
From    grid g
Inner Join abreviations a ON(1 = 1)
Where Case  When InStr(a.VARIANTS, '*' || Upper(g.PART_1) || '*') > 0 Then a.TXT || 1
            When InStr(a.VARIANTS, '*' || Upper(g.PART_2) || '*') > 0 Then a.TXT || 2
            When InStr(a.VARIANTS, '*' || Upper(g.PART_3) || '*') > 0 Then a.TXT || 3
       End Is Not Null
Order By g.ID
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
ID    NMBR  STREET          NEW_STREET        
--    ----  --------------- ----------------
1      123  Main Road        Main Road
2       34  Elm Street       Elm Street
3        1  Broad Avenue     Broad Avenue
4       23  Third Str.       Third Street
5       12  Broad Av         Broad Avenue
6      111  Av. Broad        Broad Avenue
7     5104  Main Rd.         Main Road
8     3498  Elm Str          Elm Street
9     1001  Third Street     Third Street
10    1001  John Doe's str.  John Doe's Street
11    1001  Str John Doe's   John Doe's Street   */
```

From the above resultset you can select any row by any condition on NMBR and/or (consistently formated) NEW_STREET column...
If you put Main SQL from above as another CTE (addresses_2) then you can execute your query from the question like this:

```sql
SELECT    ID, NMBR || ', ' || NEW_STREET "ADDRESS" 
FROM      addresses_2
WHERE     WHERE     NMBR || ', ' || SubStr(NEW_STREET, 1, 4) IN('123, Main',  '34, Elm ', '111, Broa', '1001, Thir')
ORDER BY  ID
```

```sql
/*  R e s u l t : 
ID    ADDRESS        
--    ------------------
1     123, Main Road
2     34, Elm Street
6     111, Broad Avenue
9     1001, Third Street */
```